# Cannot call from C to Java by using JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I can make the java code call to jni, but I meet the trouble when calling from jni to java, please help me by seeing the below code and result

In java:

```
public class SocketClient {
private native void nativeInit();

public void Init()
{
    nativeInit();
}
.........
    public boolean IsConnected()
    {
        Log.i("Test", "Hien public boolean IsConnected()");
        return _is_connected;
    }
.......
```

I make a call to Init method

```
SocketClient socketClient = new SocketClient();
socketClient.Init();
```

At Jni:

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_SocketClient_nativeInit (JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    LOG_INFO("Hien2 Java_SocketClient_nativeInit at jni layer");
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "IsConnected", "()Z");
    int temp = (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env, cls, mid);
    LOG_INFO("Hien3 temp=%d", temp);
}
```

The result output is below:

```
Hien2 Java_SocketClient_nativeInit at jni layer
Hien3 temp=168
```

The code in IsConnected() not be called !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `CallBooleanMethod` on the wrong object---the class object doesn't have an `IsConnected` method! It should be:

```
(*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env, obj, mid);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur guide :D I can fix it ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs a slight revision:

```
int temp = (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env, obj, mid);
```

When calling the java method itself, you need to call the object, not the class.  Check the function definitions carefully.